# Promise Pegasus R6 enclosure won’t mount on a Mac

Tags: hard-drive, mac, raid

I can’t mount my Promise Pegasus R6 enclosure on my Mac. One day it just disappeared. I can see the drive in disk utility but it can’t be accessed.  When I verify the disk is says there is nothing wrong with the disk.  I just can’t get it to mount.

Answer (score -1):

I have a brand new 8 bay enclosure, and it doesn't work out of the box. 
This is the second one I have, first one works like a charm. On the Pegasus support pages right now, sending them logs...

Comment: This sadly does not answer the proposed question.  You should edit your question, and answer the author's question, otherwise you should consider removing your answer.